# gRPC streaming: many smalls of few big

Tags: streaming, grpc, http2

I'm developing a big data transfer through gRPC streaming. I chunk the data into small pieces and send trough gRPC streaming.

I'm trying to figure out if it make sense to chunk data into small pieces and send them in parallel through the streaming channel (bottom picture) OR just send one by one in a relatively bigger size (top picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reassemble the data on the other end, then chunking it up yourself is probably unnecessary. If the chunks can be processed separately, then splitting it up might be wise. gRPC is built atop HTTP/2 & TCP, which will efficiently handle the chunking, delivery, and reassembly of large payloads itself.